# File rotation for all files in directory

Tags: powershell

I am using a script which will write the output into a .txt file and wanted have a rotation for the file. For example - the content “Hello world” is written into `events0.txt` and it gets renamed to `event1.txt` whenever the size of file reaches 1000B.

Currently the script always renames the file to `events1.txt` and now wanted to have the script rename `events1.txt` to `events2.txt` and so on increment all files in the folder whenever `event0.txt` reaches 1000B .

When file size condition is met when running the script, the file `events1.txt` does not get renamed to `events2.txt`.

Can someone suggest the changes required to make this happen?

```
$val = 0
$Folder = "X:\logs"
$Log = "X:\logs\events" + ${val} + ".txt"
Write-Output "Hello World" | Out-File $log -Append
$Len = Get-ChildItem $Log -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object -Property length -Sum

if ($Len.Sum -gt 1000) {
     $num +=1
     $archive ="X:\logs\events" + ${val} + ".txt"
     Move-Item $Log $archive -Force
```

Comment: What did you tried so far? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: it does not rename the events1.txt to events2.txt when the script is triggered and when file size condition is met.